# split an element into two or more elements depending on its children

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

***EDIT: for those that come to this in the future, this was a poorly written question. It was not what I was after. 
[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848239/split-a-node-if-it-has-certain-children) may also be of use to you.***

So, I have been trying to brush up on my `XSLT`  the past few days. I am very unfamiliar with it, spending most of my past using `XQuery` to transform my XML. I am stuck on a rather simple problem, but looking around I have not found a clear solution. Simply, I want to split some elements into two depending on its children.

For example, if my XML looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<root>
      <p>
         Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet bacon chuck pastrami swine pork rump, shoulder beef ribs doner tri-tip 
         tongue. Tri-tip ground round short ribs capicola meatloaf shank drumstick short loin pastrami t-
         bone. Sirloin turducken short ribs t-bone andouille strip steak pork loin corned beef hamburger 
         bacon filet mignon pork chop tail.
         <note.ref id="0001"><super>1</super></note.ref>
         <note id="0001">
           <p>
             You may need to consult a latin butcher. Good Luck.
           </p>
         </note>   
       Pork loin ribeye bacon pastrami drumstick sirloin, shoulder pig jowl. Salami brisket rump ham, tail
      hamburger strip steak pig ham hock short ribs jerky shank beef spare ribs. Capicola short ribs swine   
      beef meatball jowl pork belly. Doner leberkas short ribs, flank chuck pancetta bresaola bacon ham 
      hock pork hamburger fatback.
    </p>
    </root>
```

after I run my `xsl` I am left with something like the following:

```
<html>
<body>
   <p>
         Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet bacon chuck pastrami swine pork rump, shoulder beef ribs doner tri-tip 
         tongue. Tri-tip ground round short ribs capicola meatloaf shank drumstick short loin pastrami t-
         bone. Sirloin turducken short ribs t-bone andouille strip steak pork loin corned beef hamburger 
         bacon filet mignon pork chop tail.
         <span class="noteRef" id="0001"><sup>1</sup></span>
         <div id="note-0001"> 
           <p>
               You may need to consult a latin butcher. Good Luck.
           </p>
         </div>
           Pork loin ribeye bacon pastrami drumstick sirloin, shoulder pig jowl. Salami brisket rump ham, tail
           hamburger strip steak pig ham hock short ribs jerky shank beef spare ribs. Capicola short ribs swine   
           beef meatball jowl pork belly. Doner leberkas short ribs, flank chuck pancetta bresaola bacon ham 
           hock pork hamburger fatback.
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this is obviously an `HTML` `<p>` cannot have a `<div>` as a child, let a lone another `<p>` as a grandchild. This is just invalid. A browser, such as chromium, may render the first paragraph ending when it hits the `<div>`, wrapping, appropriately, the note in its own `<p>`, but leaving the text after the note orpahened. So that any CSS applied to the `<p>` will fail to be applied.

**How would I split one `<p>` element into two depending on the elements descendants?**

**Desired output**

```
  <html>
    <body>
       <p>
             Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet bacon chuck pastrami swine pork rump, shoulder beef ribs doner tri-tip 
             tongue. Tri-tip ground round short ribs capicola meatloaf shank drumstick short loin pastrami t-
             bone. Sirloin turducken short ribs t-bone andouille strip steak pork loin corned beef hamburger 
             bacon filet mignon pork chop tail.
             <span class="noteRef" id="0001"><sup>1</sup></span><
</p>
             <div id="note-0001"> 
               <p>
                   You may need to consult a latin butcher. Good Luck.
               </p>
             </div>
<p>
               Pork loin ribeye bacon pastrami drumstick sirloin, shoulder pig jowl. Salami brisket rump ham, tail
               hamburger strip steak pig ham hock short ribs jerky shank beef spare ribs. Capicola short ribs swine   
               beef meatball jowl pork belly. Doner leberkas short ribs, flank chuck pancetta bresaola bacon ham 
               hock pork hamburger fatback.
       </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have abstracted my question slightly, so the following `XSL` of what I have tried could be slightly off.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd" version="2.0">


<xsl:template match="/">

        <html>
          <body>
             <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </body>
        </html>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template


    <xsl:template match="note.ref">
        <span class="noteRef" id="{@id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="super">
        <sup>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </sup>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="note">
          <div id="note-{@id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post the output you want to create for the input you have posted and explain how you want to split elements. If you want to use XSLT 2.0 you might also want to tag the question with that version as that allows anyone wanting to help to use the more advanced features of XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, While I believe my desired output is clearly stated in the question I agree that sometimes just reading blocks of code is simpler. I will add those changes to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming an XSLT 2.0 processor I think using `for-each-group` can help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[not((.//p, .//div))]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[.//p, .//div]">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean((self::text(), self::note.ref))">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
        <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current()/@*, current-group()"/>
        </p>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note.ref">
    <span class="noteRef" id="{@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="super">
    <sup>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </sup>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note">
      <div id="note-{@id}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The patterns `p[not((.//p, .//div))]` and `p[.//p, .//div]` and the `group-adjacent` expression `boolean((self::text(), self::note.ref))` might need to be extended to cover other types of nodes you expect in the input and that need the same processing.

Comment: +1 @MartinHonnen I'll likely end up accepting this answer as it does work, but I hope to keep this question open a little bit longer in hopes to solicit other answers. My problem is what happens when I put in other elements. I should've put those other elements in my question, I know. But I thought I would be able to modify the `xslt` easier. I guess I am having a harder time picking XSLT then I thought I would.  Currently I have two issues that are stumping me. 1.) an id on the `<p>`'s is being output as text in instances where the paragraph contains only text.

Comment: 2.) my first pragraph has 'Bacon' wrapped in a `<highlight>` tag. which is to be transformed to a classed `<span>`, however,  it is outputed like: `<p>
         
      </p><span class="highlight-italic">Bacon</span><p>ipsum dolor sit amet....`

Comment: thank you, your answer has answered my question, however, my question was not the question I shouldve asked. I have asked a new question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848239/split-a-node-if-it-has-certain-children

Answer (score 1):

This may be too simplified, but you could try matching the `text()` in a `p` that contains a `note` and wrapping it (along with any `note.ref` following the `text()`)...

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <p>
        Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet bacon chuck pastrami swine pork rump, shoulder beef ribs doner tri-tip 
        tongue. Tri-tip ground round short ribs capicola meatloaf shank drumstick short loin pastrami t-
        bone. Sirloin turducken short ribs t-bone andouille strip steak pork loin corned beef hamburger 
        bacon filet mignon pork chop tail.
        <note.ref id="0001"><super>1</super></note.ref>
        <note id="0001">
            <p>
                You may need to consult a latin butcher. Good Luck.
            </p>
        </note>   
        Pork loin ribeye bacon pastrami drumstick sirloin, shoulder pig jowl. Salami brisket rump ham, tail
        hamburger strip steak pig ham hock short ribs jerky shank beef spare ribs. Capicola short ribs swine   
        beef meatball jowl pork belly. Doner leberkas short ribs, flank chuck pancetta bresaola bacon ham 
        hock pork hamburger fatback.
    </p>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0** (would work as 1.0 also)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*|processing-instruction()|comment()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root">        
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[note]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[note]/text()">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::note.ref" mode="keep"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="note">
        <div id="note-{@id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="note.ref"/>
    <xsl:template match="note.ref" mode="keep">
        <span class="noteRef" id="{@id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="super">
        <sup>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </sup>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet bacon chuck pastrami swine pork rump, shoulder beef ribs
         doner tri-tip tongue. Tri-tip ground round short ribs capicola meatloaf shank drumstick
         short loin pastrami t- bone. Sirloin turducken short ribs t-bone andouille strip steak
         pork loin corned beef hamburger bacon filet mignon pork chop tail.<span class="noteRef" id="0001"><sup>1</sup></span></p>
      <div id="note-0001">
         <p>You may need to consult a latin butcher. Good Luck.</p>
      </div>
      <p>Pork loin ribeye bacon pastrami drumstick sirloin, shoulder pig jowl. Salami brisket
         rump ham, tail hamburger strip steak pig ham hock short ribs jerky shank beef spare
         ribs. Capicola short ribs swine beef meatball jowl pork belly. Doner leberkas short
         ribs, flank chuck pancetta bresaola bacon ham hock pork hamburger fatback.
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 @DanielHaley, thank you, your answer has also answered my question, however, my question was not the question I shouldve asked. I have asked a new question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848239/split-a-node-if-it-has-certain-children